# General Access type Ada

Tags: pointers, types, ada

I am still confused on how `all` keyword works in a general access type

what's the difference between:

`type int_access is access all Integer;` to `type int_access is access Integer;`

for example:

```
type int_ptr is access all Integer;

Var : aliased Integer := 1;

Ptr : int_ptr := Var'Access;
```

the code works fine but if I remove the `all` keyword it gives an error that *result must be general access type* and I must add `all`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pool-specific access types -- those without the "all" -- can be used only for objects allocated in the heap (or in some user-defined storage pool) with the "new" keyword.

So this is OK:

```
type Int_Ptr is access Integer;
Prt: Int_Ptr := new Integer;
```

General access types -- those with the "all" -- can be used both for heap-allocated objects, and for any other object that is marked "aliased". So this is also OK:

```
type Int_Ptr is access all Integer;
Prt: Int_Ptr := new Integer;
```

So the rules, in brief, are:

- without "all": only objects allocated with "new"
- with "all": in addition, any object marked "aliased".

Answer (score 2):

Explained here: [Memory Management with Ada 2012](http://video.fosdem.org/2016/aw1124/memory-management-with-ada-2012.webm).